# Cannot find module http-errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am having this error with npm start command where i am facing issue with my node.js services.

Node.js v18.16.0

We have already tried
`npm i -g stylelint@version npm install @types/node --save`
, but still facing issues.

Here is my package.json file

Here is the attached package.json file

```
{
  "name": "iscoper-step-coverage",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/www"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sap/hdbext": "^7.1.4",
    "@sap/xsenv": "^3.1.0",
    "@sap/xssec": "^3.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cron": "^1.8.2",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "sap-cf-axios": "^0.2.30"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^12.1.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What errors????